# QGIS Shapefile warps when zooming out

Tags: qgis, shapefile, canada

I'm working on a project in QGIS right now that uses Canada and Canadian waterbodies as a basemap. However, the waterbodies file I was provided seems to warp in the Northwest Territories when you zoom out to see the complete map.

I've looked for a replacement shapefile online but I haven't found a suitable replacement so I'm trying to fix the issue instead.

Apologies if I've left anything out, this is my first post.

[image: Image of the Canada basemap with the area of trouble marked by the red rectangle]

[image: shapefiles fix themselves when zoomed in]

[image: closer view of the issue]

Comment: what projections are your data and the project?

Comment: It might also be due to an spatial index that has some errors in it. That could easily checked by creating a new one and also calculating the extent again. This can be found in the layer options under "general" at "coordinate reference systems". There you have "create spatial index" and "update extent".

Comment: Ian, I'm using WGS 84. All of my other shapefiles are in that projection (including the Canada basemap) except the waterbodies one was not; it was in some indiscernible projection of jumbled words. I changed it to WGS 84 and it suddenly grew giant and now dwarfs all the other shapefiles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is caused by points too far north, and too far west.

For the too far north, it occurs when the source is not in lat-long, but another projection such as Lambert conformal conic (used by the government), and then the data is changed to a un-projected coordinate system. The solution is to remove the few vertices that are too far up north.

The second issue is on the west of Alaska. This area cuts the 180 deg line and brings all kind of representation issues. In your image is seems the line from top north to top west does not go through Canada but through the other side of the world. The solution is to remove the few vertices west of -179.9.

As for a reliable data source, you can check the [census geo files](http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/bound-limit/bound-limit-2016-eng.cfm) from Statistics Canada

Comment: Unfortunately I after deleting a large number of vertices to the far west and North I was unable to resolve the issue. However, using the data source you provided I got a new shapefile of the coast to replace the one I was using. Thank you!